# How to get properties that don't have get/set using reflection?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to extract all public properties (whether they use get/set or not) of a class using reflection. However, I find that I can only retrieve the properties that use get/set following [Get property value from string using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1196991/get-property-value-from-string-using-reflection).

```
class ClassA
    {
        public string layout { get; set; }
        public int capacity { get; set; }
        public Link[] links;
        public ClassA(int n)
        {
            capacity = n;
            links = new Link[n];
            for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                links[i] = new Link();
            }
        }
    }
```

take the above class as an example. I can only get `layout` and `capacity` through reflection. Is there any way I can get "links"?

Comment: "I'm trying to extract all public properties...Is there any way I can get "links"?" `links` is simply not a property. It is a field and there is an extra reflection method to [get the fields](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getfields?view=net-5.0).

Comment: thx! @MongZhu So if I want to get both props and fields, the only way I can do this is to scan twice, one for props and one for fields, right?

Comment: No, you don't have to scan 2 times. You ca use `GetMembers` method instead and filter the collection with MemberTypes equals to `Property` or `Field`

Comment: Side note: public fields are excitingly rare in real code... so depending on your goals getting just properties may be enough.